# Permalinks by Post Name Are Not Working

Tags: permalinks

My WordPress Project is hosted on [fatcow](http://fatcow.com). The **Post Name** permalinks, are not working, but the **Default** permalink setting does work. There are many options in google, but I didn't find a simple way to resolve my issue.

Comment: Had you asked hosting support? There are no details in your question to go by.

Comment: @Rarst I hosted. This problem is occur there only. What detail you want to solve?

Answer (score 1):

See [requirements](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#mod_rewrite%3a_.22Pretty_Permalinks.22). Most of the time it's due to server configuration.